# Conditional guard in Typescript

Tags: typescript

Im looking into making a typeguard for following case:

```js
interface User {
  email: string | null;
  name: string | null;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

interface Parent extends User {
  isAdmin: true;
}

interface Child extends User {
  isAdmin: false;
  parent: string | null;
}

const isAdmin = (user: User): user is Parent => user.isAdmin;
```

Creating a guard in the following way makes it so that the user gets cast to Parent if true but to User if false. How would it be possible to yield Child type if the guard returns false?

Comment: what is the added benefit of checking the interface type(`Child` vs `Parent`)? They both seem to have the `isAdmin` field that seems to indicate if they are an admin? You cannot check instance type of interface's because they don't exist at runtime

Comment: I want to have components that will be passed a user object and I could guard its type so I would not need to make checks for isAdmin prop in every component. So somewhere high in a component tree I do one guard check and pass the user object on to components that expect either Parent or Child props.

Comment: @David The `isAdmin` property must be of type `true` to implement the `Parent` interface; not just `boolean`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you want is a discriminated union type; all users are either parents or children.

```
interface UserCommon {
  email: string | null;
  name: string | null;
  isAdmin: boolean;
}

interface Parent extends UserCommon {
  isAdmin: true;
}

interface Child extends UserCommon {
  isAdmin: false;
  parent: string | null;
}

type User = Parent | Child
```

Now you don't even need to declare a user-defined type guard; just writing `if(user.isAdmin) { ... }` or `if(!user.isAdmin) { ... }` is enough to narrow the type of `user` to `Parent` or `Child` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

The answer above works, but if you seek for something more generic and flexible, you can go with the approach below. Some minor adjustments are needed to the `isAdmin` field, since it can't be of different types in the derived interfaces. For a better understanding, you might want to check out on TS' [Mapped Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

```
interface User {
    email: string | null;
    name: string | null;
}

interface Parent extends User {
    isParent: true;
}

interface Child extends User {
    isChild: true;

    parent: string | null;
}

const hasPropertyTrue = <T extends User, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): obj is T & {[P in K]: true} => {
    return key in obj && !!obj[key];
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
function testSolution(): void {
    const parentUser = {} as Parent;
    const childUser = {} as Child;

    if (hasPropertyTrue(parentUser, 'isParent')) {  // IntelliSense support when typing the prop name
        console.log('it is a Parent', parentUser.isParent);  // no error
    }

    else if (hasPropertyTrue(parentUser, 'isChild')) {  // error and no IntelliSense support, since 'isChild' is not found among the props of Parent
        console.log(parentUser.isChild);  // error
    }

    else if (hasPropertyTrue(childUser, 'isChild')) {  // IntelliSense support when typing the prop name
        console.log('it is a Child', childUser.isChild);  // no error, and also IntelliSense support when typing the prop name
    }

    else if (hasPropertyTrue(childUser, 'isParent')) {  // error and no IntelliSense support, since 'isParent' is not found among the props of Parent
        console.log(childUser.isParent);  // error
    }
}
```

You can even define some helper lambdas, and use them like this:

```
const isParent = (obj: Parent) => hasPropertyTrue(obj, 'isParent');
const isChild = (obj: Child) => hasPropertyTrue(obj, 'isChild');

function testSolution(): void {
    const parentUser = {} as Parent;
    const childUser = {} as Child;

    if (isParent(parentUser)) {
        console.log(parentUser.isParent);  // no error
    } else if (isChild(childUser)) {
        console.log(childUser.isChild);  // no error
    }
}
```

---

I imagine that you were looking for a kind of type guard that would a type check based on a ternary condition, so this might not be 100% the solution you wanted. But AFAIK is the closest you can get in the current version of TS.

The benefit of it is that you can use if for whatever interface hierarchies and properties inside them, and even extend it to guard types by looking at more than one property. All these while you keep the IntelliSense support working.

Comment: I think by `key in obj && !!key;` you meant to write `key in obj && !!obj[key];`. Note that this doesn't let you write `if(isParent(...)) { ... } else { ... }` to narrow to type `Child` in the `else` branch, which is the problem in the original question.

Comment: @kaya3 Yes, you are right for both. For the former I'll edit my answer now, thanks.


And for the 2nd, that's exactly why I added the "disclaimer" at the bottom of the answer, regarding the ternary type guard, which my answer does not provide (and again, AFAIK TS does not support it currently).